# Is it possible to target IE8's compatibility view in CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

Is this possible? I'd of assume that compatibility view is much like the older IE's, so I tried

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
 css goes here
<![endif]-->
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work inside a css file. It only works in html. You can create a specific ie.css and put the <link> inside a conditional comment.

Answer (score 0):

That says: "if IE version is *l*ower *t*hen to 8.
Try:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
 css goes here
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

A valuable resource for dealing with IE8, doctypes, and standards vs. quirks mode is found in [Activating Browser Modes with Doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/).  Make note of the X-UA-Compatible header/meta tag.  Also note that your if is targeting anything less than "lt" IE 8, which means you'll never trigger your CSS in IE 8.